# Ant Design Components - Inside function of antd components "this" is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ant design components,inside components function "this" is undefined or missing.so,for few components i used temp variable to change state when data gets changed and i think  that's not proper way to change/handle  state.I've read about on docs of ant design and other blogs but can't find any  precise solution.Here i'm putting a "confirm" components code snippets.

```
  confirm({
            title: "Some thing i wanna do which i need to confirm",
            onOk() {
                //here i need this to change
                alert(this.state.RegisterDetail.FirstName);

            } ,
            onCancel() { }
        });
```

Comment: How is the confirm function being called ?

Comment: Thnxx... for u r early response.  <Button  onClick={() => this.myActionMethod(record)}>Some Aaction</Button>. In which myActionMethod() contains confirm part

Answer (score 1):

Please try following approach. this is different inside function  as in confirm method this is representing confirm function and not your React class.

```
const onOk = this.functionThatCallAlert
confirm({
        title: "Some thing i wanna do which i need to confirm",
        onOk ,
        onCancel
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you are given a template with destructured object properties. Try turning that into an import statement if it is undefined, and if it is still undefined try adding Ant to your project as a node module or other type of import or dependency- check the docs.

```
const { Categories, List, subtitle } = antd;

const { Step } = Steps;

const steps = [
```

Into:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Categories, List, subtitle } from 'antd';

const { Step } = Steps;

const steps = [
```